# Vue - pass prop via router to component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, router

I have a component with the object "project_element" and I want to transfer the object to another component through the "vue-router".

This is the code from my first component which opens the second component if the user clicks on the button.

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'project', params: { project_url: project_element.project_name, project_element: project_element} }">
     <b-button> Open </b-button>
</router-link>
```

This is the code from my Vue Router in index.js

```
{
  path: '/projects/:project_url',
  component: SingleProjectViewApp,
  name: 'project',
  props: { project_element:  project_element }
},
```

I already managed to set the "project_element.project_name" to the url but I also need the "project_element" itself in my second component.

In the compenent I have set the object in the "props section"

```
props: {
  project_element: {
    type: Object,
    required: true
  }
},
```

The problem is in the Vue Router, I can't pass the project_element like a variable, only with quotation marks. But then I get an error because obviously the component expected an object and not a string.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your router

```
path: '/projects/:project_url?',
component: SingleProjectViewApp,
props(route) {
      const props = {
        projectElement: route.params.project_url
      };

      return props;
    }
```

and in your props change "project_element" to "projectElement" (generally you want to do camel case in vue props)

```
props: {
  projectElement: {
    type: Object,
    required: true
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came to my mind is `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`. Although I am not sure this is a perfect solution.

Any way try this:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'project', params: { project_url: project_element.project_name, project_element: JSON.stringify(project_element)} }">
     <b-button> Open </b-button>
</router-link>
```

```
// router.js
{
  path: '/projects/:project_url',
  component: SingleProjectViewApp,
  name: 'project',
  props(route) { 
    return {
      project_element:  JSON.parse(route.params.project_element),
    }
 }
},
```

**Note**: I honestly think this is an antipattern and you should use different aproach for comunicating through components. `custom-events`, `centralized-state`, `event-bus` or even `provide & inject` will all be better for that kind of work.

Comment: I honestly thnk this is an antipattern and you should probably use different aproach for comunicating through components. I'm talking about `custom-events`, `centralized-state`, `event-bus` or even `provide & inject` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

```
routes: [
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'start',
  component: Start,
  meta: {
    my_data: "my data here",
  },
},]
```

to get data inside the component

```
this.$route.currentRoute.meta.my_data
```

**UPDATE**

```
this.$route.push("/"+ JSON.stringify(data) )



routes: [
{
  path: '/:data',
  name: 'start',
  component: Start,

},]
```

to get data inside the component

```
JSON.parse(this.$route.params.data)
```